# Backing up files

Tags: files, find, backup, gzip

I would like to backup all files older than 90 days and greater plus gzip them.  I could execute:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime 90 -exec gzip "{}" \;
```

Problem with this command is it includes files 90 days old and not older ones.  So it will gzip June's files but not May's.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-mtime +90` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

for exactly 90 it should be 
    -mtim +89

Answer (score 2):

From `man find`

```
+n     for greater than n,
-n     for less than n,
 n      for exactly n.

-mtime n
    File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.
```

So the correct line to backup files modified more than 90 days ago, will be

```
$ find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +90 -exec gzip {} +
```

Comment: The man page I was using did not include that info.  Thanks for the reference!